# Migrate Visual Composer to Thrive Architect

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Is there a way to migrate content made with visual composer to thrive architect? I could not find any script or plugin.

Or can I use visual composer and thrive on one installation and migrate the content manually? For example: On the post X I am using only visual composer and on the post Y Thrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Editor (like Visual Composer and Thrive Plugin) are not possible to installation in one website url as you are asking here.

Get the more details, you can follow the link -

[Visual Composer and Thrive Content Builder – Which is the Best WordPress Page Builder Plugin?](https://winningwp.com/visual-composer-beaver-builder-or-thrive-content-builder-compared/)